# Using dll with ctypes in python

Tags: python, ctypes

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MEASURE_VALUE
{
    public byte byDataInfo;
    public byte byJudge;
    public byte byTimZero;
    public float fValue;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MEASURE_DATA
{
    public byte byYear;
    public byte byMonth;
    public byte byDay;
    public byte byHour;
    public byte byMinute;
    public byte bySecond;
    public byte byMillsecond;
    public uint dwPulseCnt;
    public byte byTotalJudge;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
    public MEASURE_VALUE[] stMesureValue;
}

MEASURE_DATA stMeasureData = new MEASURE_DATA();
int rc = NativeMethods.GetMeasurementValue(ref stMeasureData);
```

I am trying to use a DLL with ctypes in Pyton. I want to access the ethernet port with this library and get data from there. As above, I have examples in C#. The data I get with C # is correct, but what I get with Python is wrong. When I make various changes, the data I get with Python does not change while the normal data is changed.

c#: 12.4359,-10000000000,-10000000000,-10000000000 ...

Python: 7.174648137343064e-43,1.401298464324817e-45,1.401298464324817e-45,1.401298464324817e-45 ...

```
class MEASURE_VALUE(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("byDataInfo", ctypes.c_ubyte),
        ("byJudge", ctypes.c_ubyte),
        ("byTimZero", ctypes.c_ubyte),
        ("fValue", ctypes.c_float)
    ] 

class MEASURE_DATA(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("byYear", ctypes.c_ubyte),
        ("byMonth", ctypes.c_ubyte),
        ("byDay", ctypes.c_ubyte),
        ("byHour", ctypes.c_ubyte),
        ("byMinute", ctypes.c_ubyte),
        ("bySecond", ctypes.c_ubyte),
        ("byMillsecond", ctypes.c_ubyte),
        ("dwPulseCnt", ctypes.c_ushort),
        ("byTotalJudge", ctypes.c_ubyte),
        ("stMesureValue", MEASURE_VALUE*16)
    ]

lib = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("LSIF.dll")
measureData = MEASURE_DATA()
result = lib.GetMeasurementValue(ctypes.byref(measureData))
```

Could you help me find out where I made the mistake?

Comment: Try adding `_pack_ = 1` before `_fields_`

Comment: Thanks. I added. Looks more consistent but again wrong results. Now the data is : 5.994908973212643e-39, 7.643727753601324e-38, 7.643727753601324e-38 ...

Comment: What if you `print(measureData.byYear)` ?

Comment: It's true from byYear to byTotalJudge. But only stMesureValue is wrong.

Comment: You would need `_pack_ = 1` for that too.

Comment: When I changed the "_pack_ = 1"  results are changing too.  But not expected values.

Comment: It's fixed when _pack_ = 4. The "pragma pack (_pack_)" property was important for "ctypes structure". When _pack_ is 4 set, it tells the address to be set to addresses that are multiples of 4.

Comment: Well done, it really depends on how the DLL was created, There are cases where 1, 4 or 8 are used.